# Can command aliases be added to a DOS shell automatically?

Tags: shell, powershell, dos

Is there a way to make all DOS shells on my Windows 7 system have this command alias?

```
doskey h=doskey /history
```

Is this possible, in the same way that a Bash shell can load a .bash_profile ?   I am looking for an answer that does not require PowerShell.

Comment: This appears to be similar to the question: http://superuser.com/questions/150244/command-aliases-in-dos The answer that was upvoted in that question seems more detailed than the answer that was accepted. While researching this question, I found out that the old autoexec.nt and config.nt are no longer supported in Windows 7, but might work for you if you are running an older version of Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well DOS isn't really the right word here.  In current versions of Windows, you have the CMD.exe shell that has many of the same commands as DOS (dir, copy, etc).  You may also have PowerShell.  In PowerShell it is easy to configure an alias to always be available. Create a file called `$home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` and create your alias like so:

```
New-Alias h Get-History # Don't execute as it already exists
```

However, PowerShell has already created this particular alias for you. Just open PowerShell, execute a few commands and then execute `h`.

As for CMD.exe this [blog post](http://www.uberullu.com/alias-in-windows-command-line-ms-dos-how-to/) describes how to configure CMD.exe to do the same.

Comment: Based on your answer I went so far to create a batch file (see below) that will register the profile script for you.

Answer (score 1):

In short: No. The command processors (cmd.exe and command.com) do not support aliases as you know them from bash and other shells.

Longer answer: you could create a "fake" alias by crafting clever batch files that take the arguments (%1 etc.) and pass them along to to the real command. This has the potential to break down in many glorious ways but it might provide a serviceable workaround in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Keith Hills  answer, here is the batch file I created to do this:

```
@ECHO OFF 
:: to install, place this dos_profile.bat script in the location you want 
:: it to reside and then run this batch script with the argument "register"
ECHO Commands defined by dos_profile.bat : F7, h, ls, cp, mv
IF "%1"=="register" (
  REG.exe ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%CD%\dos_profile.bat" /f
  ECHO The DOS profile is registered.  Load a new command prompt and test a command.
)
@DOSKEY LS=DIR $* 
@DOSKEY CP=COPY $* 
@DOSKEY MV=MOVE $* 
@DOSKEY H=DOSKEY /HISTORY
```